# Why is that if $a\in\overline{A}$ then for every $n>0$ we have $B(a,1/n)\bigcap A \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I don't quite understand one thing here:

> Why is that if $a\in\overline{A}$ then for every $n>0$ we have $B(a,1/n)\bigcap A \neq \emptyset$.

I drew a picture below to visualize my understanding of this:[image].

Well, as you see it's not quite clear why the ball has some intersecting points with $A$.

I know the defintion of closure, which is:

> The closure of $A,\overline{A}$, is the set $$\begin{align*}\overline{A}&:=\{x\in T: U\bigcap A\neq\emptyset \text{ for every open set $U$ that contains $x$}\}\\&=\{x\in T : \text{ every (open) neighbourhood of $x$ interects $A$}\}\end{align*}$$

Is my second visualization more accurate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at your definition of $\overline{A},$ you would realize your picture is incorrect. In fact, since $\overline{A}$ consists of those $x$ whose every neighbourhood intersects $A,$ therefore in particular the neighbourhood $B(a,\frac1n)$ of $a$ needs to intersect $A.$ In other words $$B\left(a,\frac1n\right) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$$

Comment: is my second picture more accurate?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Not quite. If you notice, there still are points in $\overline{A}$ such that you can find neighborhoods which don't intersect $A.$ In fact in a metric space, $\overline{A}= A \cup \partial A.$ Consider for example $X=\mathbb{R}, if $A=(a,b), then $\overline{A}=[a,b].$ Now try an example in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: what is $\partial A.$?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Boundary points of $A$ (all $x$ whose every neighborhood intersects both $A$ and $A^c$). So for $(a,b),$ the boundary points are $\{a,b\}.$

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space $X$ every subset of the form $B(x,r)$, for $x \in X$ and $r>0$, is open, hence by the definition of closure you just wrote it must be true that for every $a \in \bar{A}$ and for every positive integer $n$: 
$$ B(a,1/n) \cap A \ne \emptyset .$$